# How do I build the following example with Flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

How do I build the example shown in the image below with Flexbox? I don't know enough about Flexbox to get the following design to work. Please help.

[image]

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oq4m9Lha/1/) with my futile attempt.

I can do this all day with CSS floats, but I'm trying to expand my horizons.

```css
.container {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    display: -webkit-flexbox;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -moz-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
}
    
.flex-1,
.flex-2,
.flex-3,
.flex-4 {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
    
.flex-1 {
    position: relative;     
    background-color: green;
    width:200px;
    margin-left:200px;
}
    
.flex-2 {
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    flex-direction: row;
}
    
.flex-3 {
    background: orange;
    width: 100px;
}
    
.flex-4 {
    background: blue;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="flex-1"></div>
    <div class="flex-2"></div>
    <div class="flex-3"></div>
    <div class="flex-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Because Stackoverflow is not a "please do my work for me" general help forum. You get to show the code you wrote, and then talk about how that didn't do what you needed, and what you already tried in terms of [searching and debugging](/help/how-to-ask). And as a plain HTML+CSS question, you get to add that code as runnable snippet. As for not knowing enough about flexbox: teach yourself by starting at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox, _the_ resource any webdev will point you at before you can even finish "hey how did flexbox wo-"

Comment: Thanks Mike! I'll get a little code snippet up here. I failed to add it earlier.

Answer (score 1):

The .flex-1 width is set to 200px, and margin-left: auto pushes it to the right.
The .flex-2 container is set to display: flex with a flex-direction: column to arrange its inner elements vertically.
The .inner-flex elements inside .flex-2 have a flex: 1 property to evenly distribute the available space.
The .flex-3 and .flex-4 elements retain their background colors and width settings.

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-1,
.flex-2,
.flex-3,
.flex-4 {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.flex-1 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.flex-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
}

.inner-flex {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}

.flex-3 {
  background: orange;
  width: 100px;
}

.flex-4 {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-1"></div>
  <div class="flex-2">
    <div class="inner-flex"></div>
    <div class="inner-flex"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-3"></div>
  <div class="flex-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to go with your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-1"></div>
  <div class="flex-2"></div>
  <div class="flex-3"></div>
  <div class="flex-4"></div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  background-color: red;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto; //create 3 columns with auto width means it will take 1/3 width of total container
  gap: 10px; //create gap in between boxes
  padding: 10px;
}

.flex-1,
.flex-2,
.flex-3,
.flex-4 {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  padding: 20px 0;
  height: 100px;
}

.flex-1 {
  grid-column-start: 2; //This means the flex-1 class DIV starts at 2nd grid space
  grid-column-end: 4;//This means the flex-1 class DIV ends at or expands till 4th grid space
}
```

Here we use **GRID Layout** instead of Flex.Even FlexBox can also be used.I think Grid is much more easier in this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Here's one example:

#### HTML

```html
<div class="flex flex-wrap">
  <div class="basis-one-third">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="bg-red basis-two-thirds row-end">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="bg-red basis-one-third">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="bg-red basis-one-third">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="bg-red basis-one-third row-end">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```css
*, * > *, * * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex > div {
  min-height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.flex > div:not(.row-end) {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.flex-wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.bg-red {
  background-color: red;
}

.basis-one-third {
 width: calc(33.3334% - 1rem);
}

.basis-two-thirds {
 width: calc(66.6667% - 1rem);
}

.row-end {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

CODEPEN:  https://codepen.io/UncleRemus/full/poQXyVg

/// EDIT: ///

### Adding Solution the original poster went with (bubbling up from comments)

#### HTML

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">I'm the biggest!</div>
    <div class="flex-item">#2</div>
    <div class="flex-item">#3</div>
    <div class="flex-item">#4</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-container .flex-item {
  background-color: #d94a6a;
  flex: 1 1 0;                                       /*  for 2nd line to not wrap  */
  margin: 0 1px;                                                
  overflow: hidden;                                  /*  for 2nd line to not wrap  */
  min-height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
}

.flex-container .flex-item:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #3b5bb2;
  flex-basis: 100%;                                  /*  make first take full width  */
  min-height: 400px;
  margin-left:33%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: So here is my ignorance, but i was under the impression that FlexBox is just sorta' magic and that the items are able to simply expand and contract and fill in the space on their own without the need for adding specific styles to each node. I'm doing this in a for-loop and trying to get creative.

Comment: If you specify the rows, then it will fill in using `flex: 1 1 auto;`, When you're wanting to dynamically break each row based on elements filling those rows, it can get tricky. You might have a better result with CSS Grid. It will allow you to set a default grid of 3 columns per row and then you can throw in an element that takes up multiple columns &/or rows. It's very versatile.

Comment: Here's an example of css grid for you: https://codepen.io/UncleRemus/full/GbdyQG

Comment: Ronnie - this is EXACTLY what I was looking for!!! https://codepen.io/jakeseymour/pen/BaGgzeW
Thanks! - I can iterate over my loop and just add a unique className to my code on the fly

Comment: @RonMcCranie remember to not just give new code, but explain _why_ it's the way it is =)

Comment: @Mike - He didn't give up new code - he pushed me in the right direction and I solved it from there.  All someone needs sometime is to be shown where the ocean is located and they'll start fishing!

Comment: @RonMcCranie - i solved it with FlexBox as well - very minimal code! and allows for 2 lower boxes, or 3 based on what gets spit out of my loop. Thanks for the help!

https://codepen.io/jakeseymour/pen/mdQZrLM

Comment: @jake that's not what Stackoverflow is for though, comments are to push you in the right direction, [answer posts are for answers](/help/how-to-answer), so at the very least this answer needs an explanation of what the code shown does, and why that's useful (because future visitors will need to know that in order to identify whether or not this answer will help _them_ solve their problem).

Comment: @jake - "he pushed me in the right direction and I solved it from there" - I agree with Mike here, because this answer isn't just for _you_, it is for _all future readers_.  A "good" answer should explain things like why things were failing in the initial question code, what was changed for the answer and _why_ those changes make things work, or if the answer uses a significantly different approach - why that approach is better and how it works. A future reader shouldn't have to read all the comments to figure out the answer.